# is there an admin API for keycloak to get the OIDC installation JSON

Tags: keycloak

I have tried this URL : http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2018-September/015665.html,  though with no help.
i have an access token to call admin API's

Comment: Please have a look on this [link](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/4.4/server_admin/#keycloak-server-oidc-uri-endpoints)

Comment: Is this JSON accessible through the admin console utility? I guess it is. Then, why not open a browser console (F12) and check what the browser is requesting for (the browser acts as a mere KC client here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xtreme Biker is right.
I could get the url from UI console.

> /realms//clients//installation/providers/keycloak-oidc-keycloak-json

using client name, client-id can be retrieved using endpoint

> /auth/admin/realms/${realm}/clients?clientId=

The catch is the access token that has to be supplied to the admin endpoints to respond successfully. 
Access token shall be retrieved using a credentials of a user who has 'manageclients' access to the client role of the realm under which the client is registered.